# extracting csv data and plotting 2D array using scala and processing

Tags: arrays, scala, plot, processing

I was wondering if anybody might be able to shed some light on this problem, I'm quite new to scala and generally non R programming, so i'm still learning some of the ropes so to speak.

What i'm trying to do is plot a 2D array, so a grid of squares on a gray scale with a darker colour representing a higher value. I have a csv file of x and y locations on the grid and a third value z which will be represented by the colour.

I've written two pieces of code which do what I want, one extracts data from a csv file, the other plots the type of data that is extracted. The problem I have is getting them to work together.

So piece of code 1 extracts data which is as follows:

x,  y,  z

50, 16, 52

21, 25, 29

13, 12, 445

etc...

code:

```
import scala.io.Source
import java.io._

///////extract the data
object DataExtractor extends App {

  def using[T <: Closeable, R](resource: T)(block: T => R): R = {
    try { block(resource) }
    finally { resource.close() }
  }
      for (line <- io.Source.fromFile("C://~//TestData.csv").getLines.drop(1)) {
         val array = line.split(",")
        try {
          val xloc = array(0)
          val yloc = array(1)
          val intense = array (2)
      }catch { case ex: Exception => }
      }
}
```

This gives me a value from each line of the csv the x axis location (xloc), y axis (yloc) and what will be the intensity value (intense) in order to plot how darkly shaded the grid square is.

The second piece of code plots a 2D array using "processing"

```
/////////plotting data
import processing.core._
class FT extends processing.core.PApplet {

  val xloc = 9 //define locations
  val yloc = 1
  val intense = 4 //define intensity of colour
  var grid: Array[Array[Cell]] = _

  var cols: Int = 100 // grid size
  var rows: Int = 100

  override def setup() {
    size(200, 200) //window size
    grid = Array.ofDim[Cell](cols, rows)

    for (i <- 0 until cols; j <- 0 until rows) {
      grid(i)(j) = new Cell(i * 10, j * 10, 10, 10, i + j) //cell size
    }
  }

  override def draw() {
    background(0)
    for (i <- 0 until cols; j <- 0 until rows) {

      grid(i)(j).display()
      grid(i)(j).height()
      grid(i)(j).xl()
      grid(i)(j).yl()
    }
  }

  class Cell(var x: Float,
             var y: Float,
             var w: Float,
             var h: Float,
             var strength: Float) {

    def display() {
      stroke(255)
      fill(strength)
      rect(x, y, w, h)

    }
    def height() {
      strength = intense
    }
    def xl() {
      x = xloc
    }
    def yl() {
      y = yloc
    }
  }

}
```

As you can see, in my second piece of code i've given xloc, yloc and intense arbitrary values. What i'm trying to do is to loop through a csv file and for each line plug in the data to the plotting code so the final result is a grid with differing colour intensities based on the x, y and z values in the csv file.

Any help will be much appreciated as i'm still trying to figure out how one links chunks of code together in scala.

Edit:

So what i've tried is to integrate the two pieces of code, however I'm running into a new problem which is that scala will not initialize a local varaible within a method (var grid). But by moving grid outside of the loop it can no longer access the Cell class...any pointers or ideas would be much appreciated

```
import processing.core._
import scala.io.Source
import java.io._



class FT extends processing.core.PApplet {

  for (line <- io.Source.fromFile("C:~TestData.csv").getLines.drop(1)) {

        try {
          val array = line.split(",")
 var xloct = array(0)
          var yloct = array(1)
          var intenset = array (2)
          val xloc = xloct.toFloat
          val yloc = yloct.toFloat
          val intense = intenset.toFloat

  var grid: Array[Array[Cell]] =_ // error "local variables must be initialized"

  var cols: Int = 100 // grid size
  var rows: Int = 100

   def setup() {
    size(200, 200) //window size
    grid = Array.ofDim[Cell](cols, rows)

    for (i <- 0 until cols; j <- 0 until rows) {
      grid(i)(j) = new Cell(i * 10, j * 10, 10, 10, i + j) //cell size
    }
  }

   def draw() {
    background(0)
    for (i <- 0 until cols; j <- 0 until rows) {

      grid(i)(j).display()
      grid(i)(j).height()
      grid(i)(j).xl()
      grid(i)(j).yl()
    }
  }

  class Cell(var x: Float,
             var y: Float,
             var w: Float,
             var h: Float,
             var strength: Float) {

    def display() {
      stroke(255)
      fill(strength)
      rect(x, y, w, h)

    }
    def height() {
      strength = intense
    }
    def xl() {
      x = xloc
    }
    def yl() {
      y = yloc
    }
  }

} catch { case ex: Exception => }
}
}
```